# What does a returned function do in the directive declaration

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm learning about directive creation in AngularJS.

In the official docs, it says:

```
Best Practice: Prefer using the definition object over returning a function.
```

But it never gives an example of returning a function. It always gives examples returning a definition object.

**Question**: What does a directive do when you return a function instead of a definition object?

Comment: It's the postlink function... Check out this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14565177/3199781

Comment: ty :D. i learned smth new :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) doesn't mention anything about returning a function.

But, this [$compile documention](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)  does say:

> **Comprehensive Directive API**
>
> There are many different options for a directive.
>
> The difference resides in the return value of the factory function. You can either return a "Directive Definition Object" (see below) that defines the directive properties, or just the `postLink` function (all other properties will have the default values).

And there is an example below (see the comment at the bottom).

```
var myModule = angular.module(...);

myModule.directive('directiveName', function factory(injectables) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { ... }
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
  // or
  // return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { ... }
});
```